# Formatting cells based on value of other cells

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am making a tierlist for my project and I need to make it color coded. I color-coded the tier values with conditional formatting and now I would like to make basic macro that would format the name cells same way corresponding tier value cells are formatted.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: What specific problem did you run into with your attempt? Please include that in your question.

Comment: You should be able to do this just by adjusting the range of your conditional format to include both columns, making sure that the condition formula uses an absolute reference for the column (for example, $A2 instead of A2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just shows what @jsheeron said in the comments:

Set your conditional formula up as follows:
Select **Conditional Formatting -> New Rule...**

Then select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

[image: Select Rule Type]

In the formula, type the rule and use an absolute reference. So, for example, if your **Tier value** column is Column A, your formula would be `=($A2 = "S+")` and your style would be Purple fill.

[image: Edit Rule Description]

Finally, you would go to Manage Rules and select the rule to set the **Applies to:** range. The range should be the entire table. So, if your table data is A2:B21 it would look like this:

[image: Set Applies to: Range]

The result will look like this:

[image: Result of Conditional Formatting Rule]

Repeat this for each color you want to set up.